# User deletes text of their own question -- what to do?

Tags: discussion

The text of this [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32341/power-spectrum-of-a-pure-sine-problems) was replaced by "nt nt nt..." by the OP. Should we rollback the edit (at the risk of an indefinite back-and-forth with the OP), or delete the question? Or something else?

Since this is a useful question with two answers, I think we should try to preserve it. (Unfortunately I rejected a rollback edit by @Rob before I realized what was going on with this question).

Comment: You are right. This question already had answers and has been vandalized by the OP himself.

Comment: @jojek btw, [had to roll back](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/33606/revisions) another vandalizing edit.